# I want codeigniter to echo php errors instead of 500 internal error

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-reporting

I have currently set my Codeigniter root `index.php`'s `environment` variable to `development`.

And I haven't also enabled tiny URL mode.

I don't like to check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` every night and day!

Want my PHP errors back to the page. 500 Internal error is really the ***HARD***est method that can be used to show the error.

Note that we are working on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server with default config.

Comment: Perhaps it's not codeigniter, have you checked `php.ini` for `display_errors`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment I'm doubtful that this is CodeIgniter's issue. It's more likely that you simply have `display_errors` set to off in your `php.ini`.

If I remember correctly, CI's `index.php` contains a call to `ini_set('error_reporting', ..);` to change the default behaviour anyway, so you could always look in there first and see what's going on.

Just had a look, here's the default:

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| PHP ERROR REPORTING LEVEL
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CI runs with error reporting set to ALL.  For security
| reasons you are encouraged to change this when your site goes live.
| For more info visit:  http://www.php.net/error_reporting
|
*/
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If you simply add under there `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, it should start working just fine. Obviously the best bet would be to add a switch for your environment to set these variables, I'm not sure why it's not like that already, but here's an example:

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            break;
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem the only thing i got from codeigniter was only an 500 Internal error.(my old projects and a  clean install did the same) 
But the interesting part is that my non CI projects still worked that contained mostly php.

The tip to write out the error with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On' / ,1)
```

Solved my problem for some reason i didn't have the rights to read the codeigniter core files.

Adding ' +r ' to the files fixed the problem.

Rudi Visser
CarlosIPe
I Thank you both for the solution.